# Tags on the question edit form should be clickable

Tags: feature-request, tags

When I'm asking a question and adding tags, the names of individual tags I enter change into icons. It would be nice to be able to click on those icons to open their information page in a new browser tab (since I would not want to discard the question). That way, I could quickly check on what sort of questions use the tag, and also check more thoroughly on whether I'm writing a duplicate.

Currently, I must open the site in a new tab, and either copy and paste or type the given tag name into the search bar of the new tab. That should be doable in one click.

The icon for turning tag icons into text should appear on the far right of the tag bar. (I think it is a very rarely used option.)

Eventually, there should be a drop-down field that offer an option to change name, and open a new tab on a page listing the questions with the given tag.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the thing to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> It would be nice to be able to click on those icons to open their tags' information in new browser tabs

This can't happen, because clicking on the tags is used to edit them:

[image: TAG FHC]

[As Mr.Wizard said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114247/131541), however, the best thing to do is click the tags and then open the "Info" link in a new tab.

Comment: Yes, that is a better thing. Open a drop-down box with a small form to edit name and a link to open questions with this tag on new tab.

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my best language. If you don't understand, then explain what, otherwise I can only offer you repeating of my comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Open a drop-down box with a small form to edit name and a link to open questions with this tag on new tab" @rsk82... isn't that what happens now when you click a tag? Are you saying you understand, or, are you proposing a different solution?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I read your post too quick. This is a new solution that retains renaming and adds a new-tab link into one click on a tag and creates a more room for other things.

Comment: @rsk82 Are you intending that an ordinary user should be able to edit the tag (and the tag name) from the dropdown below the post? Why should the user not navigate to the appropriate page to edit, as is currently done?

Comment: What page ?. I am saying in context of edit post form, everything there, just for rename tags there should be one icon in whole tags bar that would change all tags back to text, and clicking an iconized tag would open a new page in separate tab. That was my original thought. Eventually both options could be merged into popping up (drop down as I called it) box. But not particular resolution is important here, it should be there an easy way for going to see what questions are people asking in tags that one is putting at the time of writing the question.

Comment: You can already change any tag back to text. What you're proposing is much more confusing. Did you not understand from my answer how you *already can* just click a tag and then click **info** to see all questions with that tag? The system doesn't need to be changed, it already does what you're needing @rsk82.